# CPanel - How to stop Apache from running as root user?

Tags: apache-2.2, root, users

```
<?php echo `whoami`; ?>
```

So this is returning 'root' and I don't know how to prevent it. I'm using WebHost Manager / CPanel which is supposed to create multiple users/vhosts and have Apache spawn it's process as that user/group. This isn't happening.

If I login to WHM and open the PHP and SuExec Configuration section, my settings are:

```
Default PHP Version (.php files)    5
PHP 5 Handler                       cgi
PHP 4 Handler                       none

Apache suEXEC                       on
```

What's wrong? How can I get Apache to run as the correct user rather than root?

Answer (score 5):

If you want each site to be running as it's own user, the correct PHP 5 Handler setting is 'suPHP' rather than 'CGI'. Once you change this you should see that your `whoami` reports the individual users.

Note that you may have to run EasyApache and select "Mod SuPHP" during that process to recompile Apache / PHP for this option to be available first. This is done under:

Main >> Software >> EasyApache (Apache Update) or on the command line `/scripts/easyapache`

Answer (score 4):

Apache itself is most probably running as the apache user but thanks to SuExec, PHP scripts that are owned by root will run as root.  That is why your `whoami` command returns the root user.

If you change the owner of the files in your document root to be "apache" or "www-data" (whichever one your server uses) then that same command will return the new owner of the file.

It's probably also worthwhile making sure that all of your PHP scripts are `chmod 555` and directories are not owned by the same user as the files.  This will allow CGI to execute the scripts but will mean that if a flaw is ever found in one of the PHP scripts it won't be able to modify itself or any of the other scripts and it won't be able to create a new script in any of the directories.  There are still plenty of things an attacker could do if they found a flaw in a PHP script but anything you can do to make it harder for them is worthwhile.